# choosing data frames from within a list of data frames

Tags: r, list, for-loop, if-statement

I am trying to select data frames from within a long list of data frames, based on whether certain columns are empty.

Here is a reproducible example, along with the code I have written to try to solve this problem. I am using one random variable as an acceptable substitute for another (here, b for c), so I am not bothered if df1 a ends up in both group 1 and group 2.

```
d1 <- data.frame(a=rnorm(5), b=1:5, c=rnorm(5))
d2 <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=rnorm(5), c = c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA))
d3 <- data.frame(a=1:5, b=c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA), c=c(1:5))

my_test_data <- list(d1, d2, d3)
group_1 <- list()
group_2 <- list()

for (i in 1:length(my_test_data)) {
if(!is.nan(my_test_data[[i]]$b)) {
group_1[i] <- my_test_data[i]
}
else if (!is.nan(my_test_data[[i]]$c)) {
group_2[i] <- my_test_data[i]
}
else NULL
}
```

I get warning messages saying:

*Warning messages:
1: In if (!is.nan(my_test_data[[i]]$b)) { :
  the condition has length > 1 and only the first element will be used*

and group 1 and group 2 are identical to my_test_data

All help greatly appreciated.

Comment: `is.nan` or `is.na` test the whole vector and return a vector of the same length of the columns, check for example the output of `is.na(d2$c)`

Comment: Thanks for that - so this approach isn't going to work. Do you have a suggestion on how I might do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Couple of issues going on in your sample code.

The reason you are getting the warning is because your if condition is returning a vector.

```
is.nan(my_test_data[[3]]$b) 
[1] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE`
```

The second problem you have is that your sample data doesn't have any `NaN` values. You have `NA` values...so `is.nan()` won't find anything anyway.

The third problem you have is that your if / else if / else isn't formatted right. The else if goes on the same line as the curly brackets `} else if () {`

A fourth problem is that `NULL` by itself doesn't do anything. You might as well leave out the `else NULL` because it doesn't do anything. Or you can change it to do something.

Instead of using `!is.na()` we can check whether `TRUE %in% is.na()`

```
for (i in 1:length(my_test_data)) {
    if(TRUE %in% is.na(my_test_data[[i]]$b)) {
      group_1[i] <- my_test_data[i]
    } else if (TRUE %in% is.na(my_test_data[[i]]$c)) {
      group_2[i] <- my_test_data[i]
    } # else {
    #   NULL
    # }
}
```

Now, your code will still have some strange lists because you are storing NULL values in the list, but I'm not sure if that's ok for what you're doing.

```
str(group_1)

List of 3
$ : NULL
$ : NULL
$ :'data.frame':    5 obs. of  3 variables:
    ..$ a: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
    ..$ b: logi [1:5] NA NA NA NA NA
    ..$ c: int [1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
```

Comment: Another trick when using vectors of TRUE/FALSE is the `sum()` command. For instance, you can do `if( sum(is.na(my_test_data[[i]]$b)) > 0) { do something }`. This command checks to see if any of the values are true because the FALSE is always zero and the sum of all zeroes is zero.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to go through that. I have learned a lot reading that and comparing it with my previous code. I'm learning to do R and taking on an ambitious analysis to teach myself - much appreciated.

Comment: @AdamSampson +1, great job explaining where OP was having trouble, though I would think it's more idiomatic to use `any(is.na(...))` instead of `TRUE %in% is.na(...)`

Comment: Great point. any() is much more readable. Sometimes my brain gets stuck. LoL.